# Get a bit of code after image url in browser

Tags: vue.js

I'm changing background image on hover.
The code for image url looks like this:

```
    background-image: url('../assets/img/project1.png');
```

But when I look in the Chrome inspector it looks like this:

```
   background-image: url(/img/project1.9fba20d0.png);
```

So when I try to change image need that code (9fba20d0) for it to work.

Why dose '9fba20d0' appear? How do I remove it or get it without hardcoding it?

Comment: Did you enabled caching ?

Answer (score 1):

I actually haven't used Vue.js, but I'm sure the random string appended to end of filename is for "cache busting" purposes.

Basically, the string changes each time you build your application so the next time you request index.html from the server it will reference the new filename (with a different random string at the end). If there was no string, the browser would look locally to find the file, which may be an outdated version, if you've made changes since last rebuild.

I'd try and understand how Vue.js is creating your production "assets", i.e. all the images and other static files and see if you have some options to change the default behavior, if need be. Might have to read the documentation pertaining to caching.

Hope that at least points you in the right direction!